# iPad Home Screen Web App Failure

Tags: ipad, html, jquery-mobile

We've got an ipad web app that needs all the screen real estate it can get.  The plan is to use the "add to home screen" functionality once the app is done.  However, we've run into a major issue when launching the app via the home screen.  When using the HTML5 doctype, the page simply seems to render as plain text (none of the stylesheets or javascript files are loaded).  Instead, using the XHTML 1.0 Transitional Doctype causes the page to render correctly, but we're using jQuery Mobile, which requires an HTML5 Doctype to work.

I've made attempts to simply use 'full screen' meta tags and such, but they don't seem to work either.  This is the current state of our header code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<!--<!DOCTYPE html>-->

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" /> 
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
    <title>PAGE TITLE</title>
    <link href="favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png" />


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />  
   <!-- cut other stylesheets and javascript files being loaded -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Vertex.Web/Content/style/tablet/tablet.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

From the research I've done, it sounds like the ipad uses a web.app instead of safarimobile.app when it launches from the home screen.  I'm wondering if this is at least part of the problem.  One other thought is that the ipad is trying to use a local cache when launching from the home screen, and it's just not liking the relative paths or external URLs when loading stylesheets and javascript.

Fun fact: using both Doctypes in the page will cause correct rendering the first time we open up the page from the home screen, but further attempts will fail due to a parse error (which is expected, since it's a terrible, terrible solution)

Comment: My website uses the HTML5 "doctype" and installs to the home screen just fine. Have you tried removing the `runat` attribute? That's the one obvious non-standard thing in your code sample; otherwise I don't see a clear cause for the problem.

Comment: The `runat` attribute is part of ASP.NET, it doesn't show up when the code is actually rendered in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. At any rate, I would look at other causes beyond the doctype, as that's not the core problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll keep trying various things, and hopefully will find what's causing the problem.

Comment: Did you try generating the full http://... urls in the href? Your app surely knows them and can do it

Comment: @naugtur I'm not sure if we tried that, but I believe we did at some point.  After more development on the app, we've realised that using the home screen isn't going to be possible.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I were you I'd do a proof of concept - the simplest possible page with html5 doctype and a tiny bit of content and see if it works and when it stops

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a manifest file, read more here

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I can't know if this will solve whatever the problem was or not, since the project has advanced since I asked the question, and the question is no longer valid.